# Sending form variable to multiple php scripts using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've been trying to figure out how to send a variable from a form to multiple pages using ajax and have each pages script alter the a div contents.

The script I have is working, but it seems like a huge waste of resources and im sure there is a simpler way.

```
// Function to process the input form
function ConsoleUpdateFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        $('#outputDiv').Typewriter({animDelay: 10,text: ajaxRequest.responseText, div: 'outputDiv' }); 

        //clear the form
        $('#inputForm').each(function(){ this.reset();});

        //hide the input form till the out has finished showing
        window.setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('inputForm').style.visibility="visible"; },ajaxRequest.responseText.length*10);
    }
}
var age = document.getElementById('inputfield').value;
var queryString = "?inputfield=" + age;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "consoleprocess.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 

//hide the input form
document.getElementById('inputForm').style.visibility="hidden";
}

// Function to process the input form
function VisualInterfaceUpdateFunction(){
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('visualWindowContent');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

        //clear the form
        $('#inputForm').each(function(){ this.reset();});

        //hide the input form till the out has finished showing
        window.setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('inputForm').style.visibility="visible"; },ajaxRequest.responseText.length*10);
    }
}
var age = document.getElementById('inputfield').value;
var queryString = "?inputfield=" + age;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "visualinterfaceprocess.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 

//hide the input form
document.getElementById('inputForm').style.visibility="hidden";
}

// Function to process the input form
function CommandExecutionFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        eval(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    }
}
var age = document.getElementById('inputfield').value;
var queryString = "?inputfield=" + age;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "commandexecution.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

I'm basically creating the same function 3 times while only changing the page to send the variable to and how to deal with the returning content. But I can't figure out how to get it working in one function.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Thank you for the help all. I believe I have solved the problem as this works fine. Of course if you see something I've done wrong let me know!

```
$('#inputForm').submit(function() {

$string ="inputfield=" + $('#inputfield').val();

$.ajax({  
type: "GET",  
url: "consoleprocess.php",
data: $string,  
success: function(data) {  
    $('#outputDiv').Typewriter({animDelay: 10,text: data, div: 'outputDiv' }); 
}  
});  

$.ajax({  
type: "GET",  
url: "visualinterfaceprocess.php",
dataType: "html",
data: $string,  
success: function(data) {  
    $('#visualWindowContent').replaceWith(data);
}  
});  

$.ajax({  
type: "GET",  
url: "commandexecution.php",
dataType: "script",
data: $string,
});  

//clear the form
$('#inputForm').each(function(){ this.reset();});
return false;
});
```

Comment: When you have jQuery loaded, you can use `$.get`, `$.post` and `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you better use jQuery `$.ajax` to send your ajax request. You are not really consistent in your code:

```
var age = document.getElementById('inputfield').value;
```

but later you use jQuery selector

```
$('#inputForm').each(function(){ this.reset();});
```

Also I think the better solution for your problem is to use `Events`. An action (click, submit, ...) trigger an event called `MyEvent`.

Then you can have an `Event Listener` that will trigger all you functions: `ConsoleUpdateFunction(event, data)`, `VisualInterfaceUpdateFunction(event, data)`, `CommandExecutionFunction(event, data)`

To resume, use jQuery `$.ajax()` [(documentation here)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and `Events` using jQuery `$.trigger()`, `$.bind()` or `$.on()` [(documentation here)](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

I hope this will help you. It will simplify a lot of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First try using Prototype or jQuery to simplify your code.
You can try sending your request to a single script instead of three and return data from PHP as JSON. See php json_encode()  and http://prototypejs.org/learn/json